# use Louvain detection for a direct graph

Tags: python, networkx

I have a database has 3 columns like this:

| f_id | s_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 506678 | 24-05-2005 |

I have made the connection to the network and make the network connected like this:

```
 path = 'data.csv'
 df = pd.read_csv(path) 

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='f_id, target='s_id', edge_attr=['weight','date'], create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

so now i want to detect communities to the direct graph but when i run the best partition it throw an error which is:

```
TypeError: Bad graph type, use only non directed graph
```

So how to detect the communities using Louvain detecting for the direct graph please any help and hint i apricate it.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the Directed Louvain :
https://github.com/nicolasdugue/DirectedLouvain

It optimizes a directed version of the modularity. Resuts are better with directed Louvain than when considering the graph as undirected. It is C++ code but there is also a Python Binding.
The python binding also allows to run ensemble clustering using Directed Louvain, which often leads to improved results.

Answer (score 1):

From the author of python-louvain:

> For the moment I have no plan to adapt to directed graphs.
>
> Modularity meaning is not very clear for a directed graph and I do not
> know a "standard" implementation of Louvain algorithms on such graph.
> **The usual way is to consider directed graph as undirected.**

https://github.com/taynaud/python-louvain/issues/28